# Adding delimiters in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, indexing

I am very new to python and have been trying to write a small code but no luck yet so I decided to post here.

I have a python list which looks something like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

I want to insert a delimiter say 'x' in this list. The problem is that the output should look something like this:

```
['a', 'x', 'b', 'xx', 'c', 'xxx', 'd', 'xxxx']
```

Here is code for one x:

```
zz = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
print(zz)
print('letters with delimiters as x')
i = 1
while i < len(zz):
    zz.insert(i, 'x')
    i += 2
print(zz)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first idea was to use all bazookas available for the job:

- use `zip` to interleave your list and another one made of x, xx, xxx, ... done using string multiplication (using generator comprehension to avoid creating a "hard" list, no need)
- use `itertools.chain` to flatten the obtained tuples

like this (first attempt, works, but room for improvement):

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(lst,("x"*(i+1) for i in range(len(lst))))))
```

variant using `enumerate` and not `zip`, slightly better (`range(len(lst))` is usually a big no-no BTW):

```
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((v,"x"*i) for i,v in enumerate(lst,1)))
```

avoiding `chain`, using listcomp to flatten the tuples (probably the sanest alternative, using more letters than symbols, definitely):

```
>>> [item for elts in ((v,"x"*i) for i,v in enumerate(lst,1)) for item in elts]
```

All 3 print:

```
['a',
 'x',
 'b',
 'xx',
 'c',
 'xxx',
 'd',
 'xxxx',
 'e',
 'xxxxx',
 'f',
 'xxxxxx',
 'g',
 'xxxxxxx',
 'h',
 'xxxxxxxx']
```

Comment: I thought this was an Ajax answer for a moment! Did you really have to do it all in a single line? You have 6(!) closing parentheses, for god's sake! Edit: I undid my downvote now that the acceptable solutions outnumber the unreadable one-liner, but I sure wish the worst solution wasn't at the top. Or anywhere in this answer.

Comment: you're right. Edited to add better variants, last one has only 2 parentheses

Comment: BTW I don't mind the downvote. I already was thinking of a better approach when you commented. Now I'll keep this bad one-liner at start with a disclaimer, so people won't think I "chameleoned" my answer & copied other answers.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a generator comprehension over the enumerated list to produce
`(character, 'x'*(index + 1))` tuples and then flatten the result.

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
>>> [x for tup in ((c, 'x'*i) for i, c in enumerate(lst, 1)) for x in tup]
['a', 'x', 'b', 'xx', 'c', 'xxx', 'd', 'xxxx', 'e', 'xxxxx', 'f', 'xxxxxx', 'g', 'xxxxxxx', 'h', 'xxxxxxxx']
```

Now this might be a little hard to read and is probably best done in two steps, with the flattening delegated to [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> pairs = ((c, 'x'*i) for i, c in enumerate(lst, 1))
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(pairs))
['a', 'x', 'b', 'xx', 'c', 'xxx', 'd', 'xxxx', 'e', 'xxxxx', 'f', 'xxxxxx', 'g', 'xxxxxxx', 'h', 'xxxxxxxx']
```

Comment: took me 3 tries to reach the same result, probably the best alternative

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre yeah, I sometimes don't get the nested comprehensions right on the first try either - and they are harder to read than write.

Comment: the only positive point in my answer is that you see my internal improvement process written _as an answer_. Start with crap proposal, then improve, then improve again ... to match your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this, creating a temporary list (`new_zz`) and appending to that.

```
zz = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
print(zz)
print('letters with delimiters as x')
new_zz = []
i = 0
while i < len(zz):
    new_zz.append(zz[i])
    new_zz.append('x' * (i + 1))
    i += 1
zz = new_zz
print(zz)
```